# R: Postpone plot() output until all lines have been added?

Tags: r

I have two plots that I make and update in real-time that look like this:
[image: R Plots]

I generated these plots with the standard functions `plot()` and `lines()`.
Since I generate and re-generate these plots in real time there is a lot of repainting and blinking going on.

Is it possible to hold off on outputting to the display until both plots are complete? (that is, until the lines have been added for both?)

Comment: It's not what they look like: it's how you built them.  I'm not sure why you care, but you could take a look at `xyplot` in the `lattice` package, which allows you to specify all datasets in one call. But, still, "repainting and blinking" is more a function of the speed of your computer's CPU and display driver than anything you do in R.

Comment: The [animation](http://animation.yihui.name/animation:start) package may also be of interest.

Comment: very good question, and also, it would be good if it also postponed the autoscaling of axes - that it would wait for all data and *then* just do the autoscaling process!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `dev.hold` and `dev.flush`.

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), type="n")
dev.hold()
for(i in 1:1e4) {
  lines( runif(2), runif(2) )
}
dev.flush()
```

Comment: Very nice! But also, it would be good if it also postponed the autoscaling of axes (xlim, ylim) - that it would wait for all data and then just do the autoscaling process! It is annoying to specify xlim, ylim manually, even using `range`. I hate it.

Comment: @Tomas: First of all, since each call to `lines` is independent of theothers, autoscaling is physically impossible. The graphics window "forgets" about the inputs once `lines` is completed, so AFAIK there's no way to compare previous data to the new data. A relatively simple workaround is simple to create variables `xrng <- c(min(data_1,data_2,[etc]), max(data_1,data_2,[etc]))` and then call `plot([blahblah],xlim=xrng,ylim=yrng)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, the workaround is much simpler using `range`, as I wrote (like `xlim = range(data1$x, data2$x, ...)`) but as I said I hate to do it. R should be able to do this for me, to remember all the scales and finally autoscale and plot. That's how a well designed plot library should work. DOT.

Comment: @Tomas: The autoscaling is possible: just use `ggplot2`. And you no longer have to worry about blinking either: the plot is only displayed at the end, or when you explicitly print it.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I thought these libraries will do it! However, I prefer to use basic library - if there is solution in it,I'd be happy.