# Combine barplot with boxplots into a single figure

Tags: r, boxplot

I have got the following barplot and boxplots:

[image: barplot]

[image: boxplots]

I need to combine them into a single figure. How can I do it?

I tried to use `add = TRUE` into the boxplots command line but they do not fit properly.

Comment: See ?par. Where you can try par( mfrow= c( nr, nc)) where nr = number of rows, nc number of columns. Run this before plotting both figures.

Comment: hi, thanks. both figures need to overlap and NOT to appear in the same picture as two different plots. I need only one plot with both figures.

Comment: You can try `dev.hold()` and `dev.flush()` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322095/r-postpone-plot-output-until-all-lines-have-been-added.

Comment: It would be easier to do in ggplot2, does it have to be in base graphs? if not I can make a workable example

Comment: yes, ggplot2 would be fine! and base graphs also! thanks

Comment: If the purpose of this graph is to show the means with the bars, then it is more conventional to overplot means on a boxplot using points rather than bars. This will probably look better and be easier to read/interpret. Just be sure to use a distinctive shape and/or colour for the means to stand out from the boxplot stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the overlaying plots using the `mtcars` data set:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

temp <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_bar(data = temp, aes(cyl, mpg), stat = "identity") + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In base `R` you can try:

```
library(ggplot2) # load data as in the ggplot2 answer 

# calculate the data for the barplot, here the mean mpg-value per cylinder 
# using aggregate
b <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl), mean)

# plot the barplot, save the x-axis position of each bar in n 
n <- barplot(as.matrix(b)[,2], names.arg = b$Group.1, ylim=c(0, max(mtcars$mpg) + 10))
n
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1

# plot the boxplot using add=TRUE 
# and the "at" argument for the x-axis positions which are saved in n
boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, at= n, add=TRUE),
```

[image]